# How can i set Viewbag value in Razor by using foreach?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq, asp.net-core, razor-pages

This is my code:

```
 var result = (from Photos in photos
                       join Projects in projects on Photos.ProjectID equals Projects.ProjectID
                       where
                         Projects.IsTopProject == true
                       select new
                       {
                           Projects.TaskMaster,
                           Projects.Location,
                           Photos.Photo1
                       }).ToList(); 
ViewBag.photos= result;
```

In Razor page i want using the foreach like:

```
<div class="row">
                    @foreach (var photoItem in  ViewBag.photos)
                    {
                      <img class="img-responsive" src="~/@photoItem.??Photos.Photo1" />
                     <li>@photoItem.??Projects.Location</li>
                     <li>@photoItem.??Projects.TaskMaster</li>
                    }
</div>
```

But i can't assign to the property of any `@photoItem`.

Comment: If you are using a razor page why use ViewBag and not a page model?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is here

```
 select new
            {
              Projects.TaskMaster,
              Projects.Location,
              Photos.Photo1
             }).ToList();
```

You should create a view model (Let's say **PhotoViewModel**) then create new PhotoViewModel

```
public class PhotoViewModel
{
    public int TaskMaster { get; set; }

    public string Location { get; set; }

    public string Photo1 { get; set; }
}
```

Then in Controller, it should be like this

```
var result = (from Photos in photos
                       join Projects in projects on Photos.ProjectID equals Projects.ProjectID
                       where
                         Projects.IsTopProject == true
                       select new PhotoViewModel
                       {
                           Projects.TaskMaster,
                           Projects.Location,
                           Photos.Photo1
                       }).ToList(); 
ViewBag.photos= result;
```

In View, it should be

```
@foreach (var photoItem in (List<PhotoViewModel>)ViewBag.photos)
```

Answer (score 1):

It's strongly advised to use a model, but the quick fix is unboxing the viewbag value to its appropriate type:

```
// @foreach (var photoItem in  ViewBag.photos)


@foreach (var photoItem in  ViewBag.photos as List<PhotoViewModel>)
```

or another way to cast:

```
@foreach (var photoItem in  ( (List<PhotoViewModel>) ViewBag.photos)
```